# Loosing graphics when doing update of Ubuntu studio from 22.10 to 23.04

Tags: updates, graphics, settings, 23.04

I tried to use the update function from 22.10 to 23.04 but I loose all graphics settings and the resolution is down to 1080.....
Any Idea what can be wrong?

Comment: What is the hardware of your system?  i.e. Video card.  There is a chance that the driver for the video card you have didn't transfer to the new version, like NVIDIA drivers installed from NVIDIA and not from the Ubuntu repos lack DKMS that is used to reinstall the driver into new kernels.

Comment: Yes you are right. it is a Gigabyte GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER OC 3X and that is Nvidia drivers I guess? The processor is AMD Ryzen 9 3900 Prosessor Tray
Socket-AM4, 12-Core, 24-Thread, 3.8/4.60GHz, 105W, 7nm

Comment: Can you please explain what  DKMS is?

Comment: If it is the Nvidia drivers that are missing... how do I go about to install them?

Comment: I have installed the Nvidia drivers and restarted without any success.... only 1024x768 available....

Comment: Sorry, last comment had an incorrect line.  Silly me for not being in front of a system.  The command to install the drivers would be `ubuntu-drivers install`.  Then it should list which driver is needed and install it from the repos.

Comment: Thank you for your help! However that did not fix the problem. So strange... I might have to reinstall?

Comment: I tried to boot in recovery mode and then exit to normal boot. There is a message that coming from recovery mode does not use the full graphics drivers... I continue and to my surprise the full resolution is recognized and all seems to work as expected. After a reboot all is back to the low resolution again. This is a mystery for me?